# How can I inspect and repair a roof with moss and other greenery on it?

Tags: roof, waterproofing

I have a pantry on my house, its attached to the kitchen but has its own slated roof and an outside wall. I have has issues with it getting damp, I have replaced the outside door as that was leaky, re-pointed the wall as it was in poor condition, now I want to check the roof.

There are patches of moss and other bits of weeds, I can't imagine they are supposed to be there, but I'm not sure what to do to get rid of them. How do I check for issues with the roof, and can I do anything about it myself if I find issues, or should I get someone in?

Comment: If you have thick moss and plants growing on the roof, I think it's safe to say you have issues with the roof.

Comment: @da01 the moss is quite think, and there are a couple of plants. What's the best course of actions?

Comment: Lichen growing on a roof is harmless. A very thin layer of algae is harmless. Anything else growing on the roof is either a problem now or will become a problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably time to replace the pantry roof. But first, you need to understand how so much water got there that plants started growing on it! Is the pantry roof a much lower slope than the house roof it's attached to? How's the flashing between the house roof and the pantry roof? Are you in a rainy climate? Could the slate roof be leaking water onto wood framing or decking beneath the slate? What are the plants consuming for nutrients? Most things don't grow with *only* water... are they rooting in some wood?

Comment: Shade + moisture = moss. Doesn't take much for moss to live on, it gets a good toehold on composition or rock without much dust available. Copper Sulphate granules can knock it down.

Answer (score 1):

You can check "slate roof central" where traditional slate roofers hang out for a referral.

A good option is during the a dry season, pressure washing along with mechanical removal.  Always be gentle on slate, and work going down with the lap of the shingles, not forcing anything up.  You can get a dozen years of growth off in a few minutes, which may be enough.  Be gentle and remove enough material you can see any flaws in slates.

Don't mess with chemical roof cleaners at first: you might not need them.

Beware of roofers that don't understand slate: they're likely to tell you you need a shiny new asphalt roof: a roof that won't last half as long as your old slate.